# C# webBrowser Document completed

Tags: c#

I'm learning C# and i want to write such a code: when the form opens enter Google and when the site loads its find "dog"

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        webBrowser1.Navigate("https://google.com");
        webBrowser1.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;
        if (webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted += webBrowser1.ReadyState That’s the stretch I couldn’t figure out what to do)
        {
             search for dogs  
        }
```

Comment: `https://www.google.com/search?q=dog`

Comment: i know that but on if (webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted += webBrowser1.ReadyState) showing red line "Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowserReadyState' to 'System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler" and i dont know what to do